# on clicking save, record is not inserting using lightning component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, aura, aura-attribute

im new to lightning, i created a lightning component to insert contact records,but when i click on save record is not getting saved.here is my code

> apex controller

`public class cninsert {
@AuraEnabled
    public static contact  cinsert(contact cnt){
        insert cnt;
        return cnt;
    }
}`

> contact cmp

`<aura:component controller="cninsert" implements="flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes" access="global" >
    <aura:attribute name="cont" type="contact" default="{'sobjectType' : 'contact'}"/>
    <lightning:input label="first name" value="{!v.cont.firstname}"/>
    <lightning:input label="last name" value="{!v.cont.lastname}"/>
    <lightning:button variant="brand" label="save" onclick="{!c.createcontact}"/>
</aura:component>`

> contact controller.js

`({
    createcontact : function(component, event, helper) {
        var action = component.get("c.cinsert");
        action.setParams({
            "cnt" : component.get("v.cont")
        });
        action.setCallback(this , function(response){
            var state = response.getState();
            var cn = response.getReturnValue();
            alert('eferferfer'+state)
            if(state === "SUCCESS"){
                component.set("v.cont",cn);
                alert("saved successfully");
            }
        });
        $A.enqueueAction(action);
    }
})`

Answer (score 1):

1. Try using case sensitive `FirstName` and `LastName` for contact fields.
2. Put debug in apex so that you know what is coming in apex and if at all apex methid is being invoked. Also add try catch in apex.

```
    @AuraEnabled
    public static contact  cinsert(contact cnt){
        try{
            System.debug('Contact => '+cnt);
            insert cnt;
            return cnt;
        }
        catch(Exception ex){
            System.debug('Contact => '+ex.getMessage());
            throw new AuraHandledException(ex.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

3. Add the else block when `state is not SUCCESS`

```
    if (state === "SUCCESS") {
                component.set("v.cont",cn);
                alert("saved successfully");
            }
            else if (state === "INCOMPLETE") {
                console.error("INCOMPLETE");
            }
            else if (state === "ERROR") {
                var errors = response.getError();
                if (errors) {
                    if (errors[0] && errors[0].message) {
                        console.error("Error message: " + 
                                 errors[0].message);
                    }
                } else {
                    console.error("Unknown error");
                }
            }
```

Now keep checking the browser log and apex log (in dev console) - it will tell you exactly what the problem is